# xtable same headers for a long narrow table break in two

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I,m new to R and LATEX(sorry for the spelling, but I don't know how to generate the classic version of latex here on OS). Anyway, here is my question.

I have a little bit long but narrow table, so I want to break them in two and make them look like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTige.png)

the latex will automatically add .1 to the headers of the right half, like "Industry"  in the left part but "Industry.1" in the right, what I want is "Industry" on both half, below is my data and code.

any helpful suggestion will be deeply appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11]{article}
\title{Privatization Report}
\author{JiaGao, PhD}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

INDUSTRY.DATA<-read.dta13("industrycode.dta")
DECRIB.DATA<-read.dta13("describe_V1.dta")
indu.count<-data.frame(table(DECRIB.DATA$industrycode2))
indu.count<-rename(indu.count,c(Var1 = "industrycode2"))
INDUSTRY.DATA<-merge(INDUSTRY.DATA,indu.count,by.x="industrycode2",
                     by.y = "industrycode2",all.x=TRUE)
na.list<-which(is.na(INDUSTRY.DATA$Freq == "NA"))
INDUSTRY.DATA$Freq<-replace(INDUSTRY.DATA$Freq, na.list,0)
INDUSTRY.DATA$Perc<-INDUSTRY.DATA$Freq/sum(INDUSTRY.DATA$Freq)
rm(na.list,indu.count)

<<echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'>>=
industryTable<-data.frame("Industry" = INDUSTRY.DATA[1:15,]$industryname,
                      "Freq" = INDUSTRY.DATA[1:15,]$Freq,
                      "Perc" = INDUSTRY.DATA[1:15,]$Perc,
                      "Industry" = INDUSTRY.DATA[16:30,]$industryname,
                      "Freq" = INDUSTRY.DATA[16:30,]$Freq,
                      "Perc" = INDUSTRY.DATA[16:30,]$Perc)

print(xtable(industryTable,caption = "Distribution of Privatization Across Manufacturing", label = "table:industry",align = c("c","p{4.5cm}","c","c","|p{4.5cm}","c","c"),digits = c(0,0,0,2,0,0,2)),caption.placement="top", include.rownames = FALSE)
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hopefully my answer is what you are looking for, but if not, please provide a snippet of your data so I can replicate what you are doing. You can do this by pasting the output of `dput(INDUSTRY.DATA)` or, if its really big, `dput(head(INDUSTRY.DATA))`. Good luck.

Comment: Your solution works very well for me.  I'm also wondering is there any way in xtable or Latex could generate table like this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Column names can repeat, just define them after creating the `xtable` object and before invoking the `print` command, like this:

```
tab<-xtable(data.frame(LETTERS[1:13], LETTERS[14:26]))

tab
#\begin{table}[ht]
#\centering
#\begin{tabular}{rll}
#  \hline
# & LETTERS.1.13. & LETTERS.14.26. \\ 
#  \hline
#  1 & A & N \\ 
#  2 & B & O \\ 
#  3 & C & P \\ 
#  4 & D & Q \\ 
#  5 & E & R \\ 
#  6 & F & S \\ 
#  7 & G & T \\ 
#  8 & H & U \\ 
#  9 & I & V \\ 
#  10 & J & W \\ 
#  11 & K & X \\ 
#  12 & L & Y \\ 
#  13 & M & Z \\ 
#   \hline
#\end{tabular}
#\end{table}


names(tab) <- c("le","le")

tab
# \begin{table}[ht]
# \centering
# \begin{tabular}{rll}
# \hline
# & le & le \\ 
# \hline
# 1 & A & N \\ 
# 2 & B & O \\ 
# 3 & C & P \\ 
# 4 & D & Q \\ 
# 5 & E & R \\ 
# 6 & F & S \\ 
# 7 & G & T \\ 
# 8 & H & U \\ 
# 9 & I & V \\ 
# 10 & J & W \\ 
# 11 & K & X \\ 
# 12 & L & Y \\ 
# 13 & M & Z \\ 
# \hline
# \end{tabular}
# \end{table}
```

Comment: That works excellent for me , thanks a lot@ Michael Davidson,